# Convert XML to Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, conversion, xml

Is there already a tool, that can convert a XML file to a Tikz-tree?

```
<node id="1" time="0">
    <info1>
      <info1a="1"/>
    </info1>
    <info2>
      <info2a="0"/>
      <info2b="2"/>
    </info2>
    ...more info...
    <childNodes>
      ...more nodes...
    </childNodes>
</node>
```

Comment: @down-voters: Please at least add a comment explaining the downvote.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: I would really like comments. Right now I interpret the -1 and close-votes as "I personally don't like your question for no reason"

Comment: Is there any particular tikz-related tree syntax you are interested in achieving?

Comment: @AndrewSwann can you rephrase your question?

Comment: `tikz` has different tree and graph drawing library/packages.  Is there one that you are commited to use, or are you flexible.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I don't know any of these libraries. I thought of displaying the infos of a node in a rectangular split.

Comment: The features are mostly described in the [standard tikz/pgf documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).  See also the [forest documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest).  The answer to your question as posed (does there exist a parser) is probably no.  But I you tell what syntax you want out, we may well be able to produce something.  Are you prepared to use `lualatex`?